# Wheres all my disk space? I encrypted a partition

Tags: kali-linux, gparted, whole-drive-encryption

In my root folder, it shows i only have 15 GB of space available. When opening Gparted, it shows an 950 gb encrypted partition. How come i only have 15GB available in my root directory?

**Update**: This question has already been answered, but i reworded it to better fit the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root partition is only 15G. The rest of the volume has not been allocated. Make another partition (using the mapped name of the encrypted disk) to access the rest of the disk.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption#Block_device_encryption